# Any way to obtain percentage coverage of fragment (pixel) by primitive in hlsl/glsl fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, shader, rendering, directx, hlsl

When the rasterizer invokes on primitive it split it into the collection of fragments (pixels). Next, the fragment shader called for every obtained pixel. Is there any way for me to have additional float parameter in my fragment shader, that will store information about how much the exact pixel is covered by the source primitive? This should have non-trivial value from 0-1 on triangle border pixels. Obviously it will be 1 on every "inside" triangle pixel.
I want rasterizer calculate and pass this value for me.
I thoight the "coservative rasterization" could help with that, but as I understand it uses for slightly different tasks (mostly for collision detection).

Also, as I understand there is no build-in method to do that. May be I can change the rasterized nature to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: [Occlusion queries](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object)?

Answer (score 4):

When rendering to a multisampled framebuffer, you can look at the `gl_SampleMaskIn[]` bitmask array in the fragment shader to detect how many samples will be covered by the current fragment. This is about as close as you're going to get, and it's not great for what you want.

Obviously, it has the limitation of having the same granularity as the sample locations within a pixel. But the full mask also may be fewer than the number of samples in the framebuffer. If the renderer decides to generate multiple fragments per-pixel during multisample rasterization, the sample mask that any such fragments will only be for the samples that this particular fragment will write.

So if you have a 16-sample multisample framebuffer, the implementation may generate 4 fragments per-pixel, each covering a distinct set of 4 samples. So the sample bitmask for a fragment will never have more than 4 bits, even though you asked for 16x multisample rendering. And there's basically nothing you can do to detect if this is happening (outside of doing tests on specific hardware). All of this is implementation-defined.

Basically, what you want isn't really available; `gl_SampleMask` is the closest you can get, and how useful it is will be very implementation-dependent.

Comment: Actually, for the sake of completeness: With the introduction of VRS, Microsoft finally defined how that bitmask (SV_Coverage in HLSL) has to look like, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/vrs ("The bits of the coverage mask adhere to a well-defined order..."), so no "implementation-defined" anymore, at least since VRS :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one could use `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` somehow for this, since as far as I understand it does exactly this, calculate the coverage of the current fragment and then modulates the fragment's alpha based on this